# Why is the canvas redrawing when clicking on the textfield in jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I use Jetpack Compose to create an application on a PC.

When creating the application, I ran into a problem. I have a Canvas on which I want to draw something and a textfield. When you click on the TextField, the canvas content is redrawn. Why is this happening? I think it has something to do with the default textfield animation, but I'm not sure. I would like to produce a rather complex rendering in Canvas and would not want this redrawing to be called endlessly again.

```
@Composable
@Preview
fun App() {
    MaterialTheme {
        Row {
            /*MandelbrotCanvas(mandelbrot, bmp){
                refreshBitmap()
            }*/

            println("Recomposition")
            Canvas(modifier = Modifier.size(50.dp)){
                println("Redrawing")
            }

            TextField(value = "", onValueChange = {})
        }
    }
}
```

To check the recomposition and redrawing, I output a message to the command line.
Here is the result of the application:

```
Recomposition
Redrawing

"I click on the TextField"

Redrawing
Redrawing
Redrawing
Redrawing
Redrawing
Redrawing
...etc
```